# Input Number Format Angular 2

Tags: angular, input, wijmo

I am stuck in a problem i want do that `wijmo-input-number` field have mask like `wijmo-date-input` field.

Example: before enter field show:

```
(___)-________
```

After enter some data:

```
(123)-1245678
```

Note: without used JavaScript and jQuery. Your answer will be high appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern that should do the trick :

```
regExp=/^(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$/
```